# rethinkdb merging two tables with only one record

Tags: rethinkdb, merging-data

I have two documents "Users" and "Roles" and i am merging these two tables records with following query

```
r.db('myDB').table('users').merge({
roles: r.db('myDB').table('Roles').getAll(r.args(r.row('roles')))('Name').coerceTo('ARRAY')
```

})

User Document:

```
{"id":  "1" ,"password":  "123" ,"roles":  "[1]" ,"userName":  "user1"} 
{"id":  "2" ,"password":  "123" ,"roles": ["1","2"] ,"userName":  "user2"}
```

its working fine when there is more than 1 Role against a user. But it return error if a user has only 1 Role the error is

"RqlRuntimeError: Expected type ARRAY but found STRING in:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `roles` maybe a string instead of an array. If that's the case, try this:

```
r.db('myDB').table('users').merge({
  roles: r.db('myDB').table('roles').getAll(r.args(
    r.branch(r.row('roles').typeOf().eq('ARRAY'), r.row('roles'),[r.row('roles')]))
  )('Name').coerceTo('ARRAY')
});
```

Comment: Can you paste your sample data?